# How do I stop Git Bash asking for more input?

Tags: windows, bash, shell, git

Sometimes in Git Bash, I'll enter a bad command such as this (ex: mongoDB):

```
db.people.insert([{name: 'John'},
{name: 'Marry'}])
asdasd
a56sf
sdfnbn
```

since I pressed enter after 'john',it just accepts more input indefinitely. I don't want to end the whole process (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>), I just want to get out of that command?

Answer (score 1):

In Unix shells, you can signal the end of your input to a given command, without interrupting or killing the command, by sending the "End of Transmission" (EOT) terminal control character, which is sent by hitting Ctrl-D. See if that works in your case.

Comment: That should work. Just don’t press it twice, or it’ll close the shell. :D